# How do I get the results of all failed call backs using $.when()

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

Say I have a deferred function:

**Attempt 1:**

```
$.when(validatePerson(123), validatePerson(456))
.done(function(data) { })
.fail(function(data1, data2) { });
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
$.when(validatePerson(123), validatePerson(456))
.done(function(data) { })
.fail(function(data1) { }, 
      function(data2) { });
```

I want to make 2 AJAX calls asynchronously, but in the fail I want to be able to ascertain which of the 1st, 2nd or both calls failed so I can display an appropriate error to the user.

e.g.

- Validated Person 1 (id 123) failed
- Validated Person 2 (id 456) failed

But I can't seem to get it to work.
In Attempt 1, the **data1** parameter only contains one of the results, and **data2** is undefined.

In Attempt 2 I get the function callback called twice with the same argument.

Comment: Is this not possible using JQuery? Will this work in IE11 as I see Promises as an ES6 thing too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.when()` terminates when the first promise you pass it rejects.  You cannot get all rejected promises with it.  You can use it with some other code to track all failures.

Here's a `$.settle()` that waits for all promises you pass it to be either resolved or rejected and returns an array of PromiseInspection objects from which you can tell which resolved and which rejected and what their resolved values or rejected reasons are:

```
(function() {    

    function isPromise(p) {
        return p && (typeof p === "object" || typeof p === "function") && typeof p.then === "function";
    }

    function wrapInPromise(p) {
        if (!isPromise(p)) {
            p = $.Deferred().resolve(p);
        }
        return p;
    }

    function PromiseInspection(fulfilled, val) {
        return {
            isFulfilled: function() {
                return fulfilled;
            }, isRejected: function() {
                return !fulfilled;
            }, isPending: function() {
                // PromiseInspection objects created here are never pending
                return false;
            }, value: function() {
                if (!fulfilled) {
                    throw new Error("Can't call .value() on a promise that is not fulfilled");
                }
                return val;
            }, reason: function() {
                if (fulfilled) {
                    throw new Error("Can't call .reason() on a promise that is fulfilled");
                }
                return val;
            }
        };
    }

    // pass either multiple promises as separate arguments or an array of promises
    $.settle = function(p1) {
        var args;
        if (Array.isArray(p1)) {
              args = p1;
        } else {
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        }

        return $.when.apply($, args.map(function(p) {
            // make sure p is a promise (it could be just a value)
            p = wrapInPromise(p);
            // Now we know for sure that p is a promise
            // Make sure that the returned promise here is always resolved with a PromiseInspection object, never rejected
            return p.then(function(val) {
                return new PromiseInspection(true, val);
            }, function(reason) {
                // convert rejected promise into resolved promise by returning a resolved promised
                // One could just return the promiseInspection object directly if jQuery was
                // Promise spec compliant, but jQuery 1.x and 2.x are not so we have to take this extra step
                return wrapInPromise(new PromiseInspection(false, reason));
            });
        })).then(function() {
              // return an array of results which is just more convenient to work with
              // than the separate arguments that $.when() would normally return
            return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        });
    }

    // simpler version that just converts any failed promises
    // to a resolved value of what is passed in, so the caller can just skip
    // any of those values in the returned values array
    // Typically, the caller would pass in null or 0 or an empty object
    $.settleVal = function(errorVal, p1) {
        var args;
        if (Array.isArray(p1)) {
              args = p1;
        } else {
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        }
        return $.when.apply($, args.map(function(p) {
            p = wrapInPromise(p);
            return p.then(null, function(err) {
                return wrapInPromise(errorVal);
            });
        }));
    }
})();
```

Usage:

```
$.settle(arrayOfPromises).then(function(results) {
    // results is an array of PromiseInspection objects and you can
    // tell which are resolved and which are rejected
    results.forEach(function(item, index) {
         if (item.isFulfilled()) {
             console.log("promise #" + index + " is fulfilled with value: ", item.value(););
         } else {
             console.log("promise #" + index + " is rejected with reason: ", item.reason(););
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this is a lot of code for just 2 ajax call backs!  Also I'm wondering what is the purpose of the array of callbacks in the fail() function then?

Comment: @user183872 - `$.when()` rejects as soon as the first promise fails so you have NO opportunity to see what happened to the other promises.  It just doesn't work that way.  You can pass multiple callbacks to `.fail()` and it's just multiple callbacks for the same event.  It will call each of them one after another, all with the same info.

Comment: @user183872 - You should think of this as a tool that is an extension to jQuery.  You add it to your project so you can use `$.settle()` any time you want to see all the results of all the promises regardless of resolve or reject.  Then, you just use it in place of `$.when()` when that's what you want.  It's not something you type out everytime you want to use it.